# Iterate over group of array and separate the output by number of iterations

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, data-structures

My code currently creates a new array for each value separated by a comma in a string.

I am trying to iterate over the values in the inner array of `results` using `results.length` as the iterator counter, but I need to separate the output of each iteration. I have used  a forEach inside a conventional for loop to iterate over the values but that does not provide desired outcome, it groups all the values together. The input string could contain any combination of strings grouped by any number of values therefore I must be generic in approach.

**Data Structure**

```
    [
      ["abc","def"],["ghi", "jkl"]
    ]
```

**Input String:**  "abc def, ghi jkl"                
**Current Output Console Log1:** abc def, ghi jkl       
**Desired Output Console Log1:** "abc" "def"         
**Desired Output Console Log2:** "ghi" "jkl"

I am trying to iterate over this

```js
var s = "abc def, ghi jkl";

var result = s.split(',').map(a=>a.trim().split(' '));
console.log(result);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  result.forEach(a => {
  console.log(a[i]);
// console.log(a // should be i ++ and so on until i = results.length
});
}
```

Comment: please consider accepting an answer , if you have found a solution here

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var s = "abc def, ghi jkl";

let data = s.split(",").map(d => d.trim().split(" "));

data.forEach(d => {
  console.log(d.join(" "));
})
```

Comment: I need them to be returned in an array so I can get their values]

Comment: If you want them as an array, then you can use remove `.join(" ")` form the above code.

Comment: Somewhere you were mentioning that you want to print them as a group and that's what exactly is happening. At least that's what everyone understood from your question.

Comment: Yes but separate groups. so [abc, def] should be returned after first iteration, then [ghi, jkl] in the second iteration and so on until the outer arrays index is met. so basically we would want to be able to use them in separate expressions within the same unit of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the second array with index from first one.

Try this:

```js
    var s = "abc def, ghi jkl";
    var result = s.split(',').map(a=>a.trim().split(' '));
    
    result.forEach(innerArray => innerArray.forEach(a => console.log(a)));
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I need to do as the more comma separated values the user enters the more time we need to iterate. I need the output to be grouped by indexes of 1 array so the should be returned in the groups that they are entered in the string @S

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
const arr = [
  ["abc", "def"],
  ["ghi", "jkl"]
];

arr.forEach(([word1, word2]) => console.log(word1, word2))
```

Comment: No sorry, it is hard to explain for me. Basically I have the code that groups them as they are in the correct data structure. I need to take the Array of Arrays which contains the values and iterate over the inner array of results which contains the strings and i need to get the value from each position 1 iteration at a time. So when for loop runs i = 0, I need to get values from my array myArray[0] = ["abc","def"}  so I must be able to return  myArray[0]. Next iteration i=1 myArray[1] =["ghi',"klm"] I need to get the values from myArray[1]. This has to continue until i = results.length.

Comment: I edited my answer, but I still don't think I'm really understanding what you're asking. If you have the array, you already have all the values. What more do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks man, unfortunately this wont scale as values aren't neccessarily entered in pairs, it could be any combo. just need to iterate over the inner array with the index of the outer array and return that croup as it's own array until the loop is over. in this case they are returned together. I need to put them in separate expressions.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I'm still not quite catching on. A few more input and desired output examples I think would help me a lot. Maybe you're looking for something like `Array.values().forEach()`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? You will be able to log the first array then the second and so on...

- abc
- def
- ghi
- jkl

This is the code to output this:

```
const s = 'abc def, ghi jkl';
const result = s.split(',').map(a => a.trim().split(' '));

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  for (let p = 0; p < result[i].length; p++) {
    console.log(result[i][p]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to explain it. Outputs need to be logged in groups so abc, def need to be logged in the first iteration of 'i' then i++ the next group logged together and so on as many groups as there are. Hope that clears it up @paulhenry

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = [["abc","def"],["ghi", "jkl"]]

for(i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  console.log(s[i].toString().split(',').join(' '))
}
```

log 1 ----> `abc def`

log 2 ----> `ghi jkl`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
var s = "abc def, ghi jkl, fgt tps fll"
```

to become something like this:

```
[
"abc",
"def",
"ghi",
"jkl",
"fgt",
"tps",
"fll"
]
```

In that case you can you use the code below:

```
var result = s.split(',').map(a=>a.trim().split(' '))

const newTab = []
// for every array inside your first array do
result.forEach( tab => {
  // for every element of the inner array do
  tab.forEach( el => {
    // push every element into a new array
    newTab.push(el)
  })
})

console.log(newTab)
```

Comment: I already have this in the snippet. I need to output them in groups as they are in the string but it has to be done in a loop because I do not know how many groups of words user will enter. @Elmehdi